# ゲームプログラミング設計について知りたい

Tags: c++

ゲームプログラムの設計について、クラスやソースファイルに分けて作るゲームの設計そのものがわからないのです。

「計算」と「描画」の二つに分けるということは調べてわかったのですが、それをどのようにしてプログラムとして組むのかがわかりません。今は「とりあえず動けばいい」という感じで組んでいますが、もう少しちゃんと組もうとするとどうすればいいのか教えてくれますでしょうか？

```
#include "DxLib.h"
#include "math.h"
//#include <iostream>
constexpr double PI = 3.141592654;
constexpr double radian = PI / 180.0;
int Key[256];
int gpUpdateKey()
{
    char tmpkey[256];
    GetHitKeyStateAll(tmpkey);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (tmpkey[i] != 0) {
            Key[i]++;
        }
        else {
            Key[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*ハンドル*/
//x:48  y : 64
//ウインドウサイズ x:640 y:480
//int pos_x = (640 / 2) - (48 / 2);
//int pos_y = (480 / 2) - (64 / 2);

int pos_x = 200;
int pos_y = 380;

int x = pos_x;
int y = pos_y;
int Select = 0;

int Count = 0;
int color;
int hResource;
int hBall;
int hCharacter[16];

int xx = pos_x;
int yy = pos_y;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char name[128];
}Menu_t;

Menu_t SelectMenu[3] = {
    {200,50,"ゲーム開始"},
    {100,100,"コンテニュー"},
    {100,150,"終了"},
};

/*計算*/
void Calc();
void Calc() {

}

void end() {

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstanve, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    ChangeWindowMode(true), DxLib_Init(), SetDrawScreen(DX_SCREEN_BACK);
    color = GetColor(0, 255, 0);
    hResource = LoadGraph("Resource.png");
    hBall = LoadGraph("Ball.png");
    hCharacter[16] = { 0 };
    int hBlock = LoadGraph("Block.png");
    LoadDivGraph("char.png", 16, 4, 4, 32, 32, hCharacter);
    int color = GetColor(255,255,255);

    int direction = 1;
    double angle = PI * 2 / 8;
    while (ScreenFlip() == 0 && ProcessMessage() == 0 && ClearDrawScreen() == 0 && gpUpdateKey() == 0) {

        DrawGraph(pos_x, pos_y, hBlock, TRUE);

    //  pos_x += 2 * cos(0.0174533 * 30);
    //  pos_y -= 2 * sin(0.0174533 * 30);

        pos_x += 2 * cos(radian * 30);
        pos_y -= 2 * sin(radian * 30);

        DrawFormatString(0,0,color,"pos_x:%d",pos_x);
        DrawFormatString(0,15, color,"pos_y:%d", pos_y);
        if (CheckHitKey(KEY_INPUT_ESCAPE) == 1 || CheckHitKey(KEY_INPUT_RETURN) == 1) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    WaitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 今の質問内容では、あまりにも範囲が広すぎて...
構造化プログラミング、オブジェクト指向で調べてみてはいかがでしょう？それで見つかる内容も膨大なので、とりあえず入門書などを1冊読んでみてはいかがですか？

Comment: ゲームエンジンにもいっぱいあって C++ のような難しい言語にこだわる必要などないんですけど、それでも DxLib が使いたいですか？　オイラなら unity + C# をお勧めしたいです。どうしても DxLib が良いということなら https://dixq.net/ あたりに膨大な解説とかサンプルとかありますので見に行ってください。最近昼間はつながりにくいんですが